# Playing song from online url is not working with http but works with https

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

As i am doing a app where i will get the song url from online and play it in the mobile it works when i try with the url that is given in the sample which has https url

but from the server when the url comes it does not contain https so it is not playing the song i dont know ther the issue is can anybody help me

String AudioURL = "https://www.ssaurel.com/tmp/mymusic.mp3";

this is the url that i use as of now it is working

String AudioURL = "http://www.madhapadal.com/Audio/Nesam/02 Nee Oravadu.mp3";

This one which is the actual url that i have to play in android which does not work

Here is the code

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.ButtonTestPlayPause) {

            try {
//                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(AudioURL));
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(AudioURL); // setup song from http://www.hrupin.com/wp-content/uploads/mp3/testsong_20_sec.mp3 URL to mediaplayer data source
                mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mediaPlayer.prepare(); // you must call this method after setup the datasource in setDataSource method. After calling prepare() the instance of MediaPlayer starts load data from URL to internal buffer.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            mediaFileLengthInMilliseconds = mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // gets the song length in milliseconds from URL

            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                String totalTime = milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                mTxtTotalTime.setText(totalTime);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_circle_outline_black_24dp);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                buttonPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
            }

            primarySeekBarProgressUpdater();
        }
    }
```

please help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: `https` working, and `http` not. Is that the problem ?

Comment: i dont know exactly if there is any issue with the url also 

but the same url plays the song in web browser

both http and https url plays well in web browser but in mobile only https is getting played dont know why